# tensorflow estimator save model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I am Experimenting with Text Classification for character_rnn (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/671baf080238025da9698ea980cd9504005f727c/tensorflow/examples/learn/text_classification_character_rnn.py).

How can i write a serving_input_fn for it ? I want to save and restore this model

extended the code to save but getting error, please help

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.utils import input_fn_utils
feature_spec = {"feature":tf.FixedLenFeature([100],tf.int64)}
serving_input_fn = input_fn_utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn(feature_spec)
```

and then

```
classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base='model', serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn)
```

and getting this error

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: {'feature': }. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

please help me.

Comment: I am using Tensorflow 1.15
pls find the code snippet here (https://gist.github.com/neuralminds/ea46e94faebc2beb7af20a0b609f1485).

I have exported the trained model as .pb files but when trying to restore for inference it throws error.

Answer (score 0):

`serving_fn` requires the features to be a `tensor`.

Please see below a sample:

```
def serving_fn():
    day_of_month      = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.int64, name='DAY_OF_MONTH')
    day_of_week       = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.int64, name='DAY_OF_WEEK')
    tail_num          = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.string,name='TAIL_NUM')
    op_carrier_fl_num = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.int64, name='OP_CARRIER_FL_NUM')
    origin_airport_id = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.int64, name='ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID')
    dest_airport_id   = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.int64, name='DEST_AIRPORT_ID')
    dep_time_blk      = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.string,name='DEP_TIME_BLK')

    reqd_inputs =  {'DAY_OF_MONTH':day_of_month,
                    'DAY_OF_WEEK':day_of_week,
                    'TAIL_NUM':tail_num,
                    'OP_CARRIER_FL_NUM':op_carrier_fl_num,
                    'ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID':origin_airport_id,
                    'DEST_AIRPORT_ID':dest_airport_id,
                    'DEP_TIME_BLK':dep_time_blk}

    fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(reqd_inputs)
    return fn
```

Based on your features and datatype, you would need to convert them to corresponding tensors.

If it helps, the above mentioned sample is available as a Kaggle notebook at: https://www.kaggle.com/jintolonappan/gbm-tf2-boostedtreesclassifier-export-to-serve